# Define input current of Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt, current-measurement, input, fet

I haven't done and studies in Op-Amp category yet but I watched a (trusted) video on Youtube and one thing is not quite logical as the next sentence: "No current flows in or out of the inputs of operational amplifier", as says Dave Jones from EEVblog on Youtube (this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FYHt5XviKc).

So, I am wondering if he meant like there is a really small amount of current flowing in op-amp on the inputs, or there isn't any of current on inputs at all?

I am sure there must be at least some current on inputs (for base if BJT or for gate if FET/MOSFET for sure).

[image]

Comment: (The 741 shouldn't be used for any argument. It's old and not used except by builder hobbyists copying old schematics. But it can be and should be studied for how it worked because it's complexity is relatively low.) The ideal opamp isn't obtainable, of course, but doesn't have any input current. The ideal opamp also has infinite gain. Real opamps will have extremely low input currents and extremely high gain, with different technologies offering different trade-offs in offset voltage and input, bias, and offset current, etc. See: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa011/sloa011.pdf

Comment: @jonk: I used to take solace in the fact that one day the million-pieces stocks of such ancient ICs will simply run empty, and TI et al. simply won't care to re-run them (if they even still have the masks to do so – compare the SA612/NE612 Philips fire disaster); but then I realized that even if that ever happens, the market for replacement in critical circuits is large enough to allow for smaller semiconductor suppliers to operate profitably by making these pricey (but the hobbiest will just assume it's normal a shitty Opamp costs 5€).

Comment: @MarcusMüller It seems old FABs never die. They just get sold cheaper and cheaper, as long as they still work and other costs (labor, repair, etc) make it feasible. They'll get used for diodes, LEDs, detectors, and whatever else they can make. (Well, at least I did trace one FAB from its earlier high-end production role down to mere diode production at Diodes, Inc., years later, once.) If someone can still make a nickel, they will. Cripes, I might even buy one if it were cheap enough. (I do non-contact temp sensor systems for modern FABs.)

Comment: @jonk, yep. But there's decreasingly much money in LM741 – I mean, way better opamps actually are much cheaper already, and at some point, the industry demand for LM741 will simply disappear for all economic relevance. I assume people like Diodes Inc, Rohm and whoelse just look at the masks they have, then look at demand, and then schedule the next run of ICs, so that their fab never stands still. This will only work as long as there's still more than 10,000pcs/year sold – otherwise, you'd just produce a couple more {MC34063 clones|24002 EEPROMS|…}. Or, if each of the 100,000 dies brings 50ct.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes. FABs need to keep running. Brokering is one way. Producing detector diodes (or anything, really, that doesn't require a lot of NRE) is another. (Diodes, Inc. was willing to make anything I wanted, if I could spec it for their processes.) I also worked with G-squared's RTP (rapid thermal processing) units, developing the temperature component of the multi-zone thermal control loop system, which are often used for "one-off" wafer production (and/or RTA -- annealing.) But I don't fully understand the marketing side, not caring so much about it.

Comment: @jonk that's pretty cool (thermal pun intended); I'm currently curiously observing the whole Multi-Project Wafer enterprises, since there's no way that I'd run a full medium-to-not-ancient-aged process wafer in the next few years. Coming from a rather FPGA-affine industry, things like the very FPGA-to-ASIC oriented BaySand [UltraShuttle](https://www.baysand.com/press-release/baysand-initiate-unique-low-cost-mpw/) things do sound promising, especially since it might, if these prices in that very marketing-y text are correct, replace FPGAs of a higher price class.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's kind of where I think things are headed! RTP pulls in the wafer process from weeks/months to mere days or less. It's hard to achieve 400 C per second rates on a 12" wafer without causing it to "potato-chip" itself. But hundreds of zones of control to deal with edge effects, etc., do make it possible. (I was working on these in the mid 1990's to late 1990's and was able to point out a cheaper way to deal with emissivity and surface variation issues that opened the door to economic means to get there.) UltraShuttle is headed in the direction I saw! Thanks for the link!

Comment: @jonk  :) Yeah, it's nice to share something interesting one finds here and there once in a while

Comment: @MarcusMüller That was really cool. I'm imagining the day where anyone can use freely available (open source) tools on Linux (or Windows), that are also idiot proof and easy to use, to develop their own custom ASIC design and get it fabricated. Should be about as easy as using a schematic layout tool, today. What's sad is that we already have such fantastic tools today and too few bother to learn to use them. When I was growing up, there were 5 periodicals and dozens of suppliers just for telescope makers like me. Today there are zero of both. (No one makes raw glass supplies in hobby qtys.)

Comment: @jonk you probably are aware of that, but if you haven't seen it yet, check out [YOSYS](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/) which is actually able to synthesize netlists from Verilog that can be placed and routed using [Arachne-pnr](https://github.com/cseed/arachne-pnr) and converted to a bitstream that uses the full abilities of commercially available Lattice FPGAs (the small, ice40 series, so not the large scale DSP fun yet) in a complete open source FPGA workflow. It's also able to map to Xilinx Series-7 technology (and does usually better, and works faster, than Xilinx' own Vivado).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh my gosh! WOW! Thanks for that link (those links, really), too!!

Comment: @jonk you're more than welcome. If I can steal more time from you with that: [Here's the author, holding a talk about that last year](https://media.ccc.de/v/32c3-7139-a_free_and_open_source_verilog-to-bitstream_flow_for_ice40_fpgas); quite something has happened since then, too, but I think this is the nicest introduction you'd get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well spotted! There is an input current, but it can be really small. It's usually specified as "bias current" in the datasheet. For older parts it'll be some number of microamperes. For specially designed JFET inputs for instrumentation amps, it can be as small as *femtoamperes*, which are [really hard to measure](http://electronicdesign.com/test-amp-measurement/whats-all-femtoampere-stuff-anyhow). (The part mentioned is the [LPC662](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lpc662.pdf) which claims 2fA input current!).

For normal analysis purposes you ignore it, but it can matter when you're trying to amplify a small signal.

Comment: What makes it so low? What is the purpose of such small amount of current?

Comment: FET and JFET gates are insulating, which makes it low. They're just not perfect insulators, hence the very small current leaking through "insulators" inside the chip. Or do you mean "why bother reducing it to such a low level"?

Comment: Yes, why bother reducing it to such a low level? I mean, if there are FETs in op-amp then the low current level is understandable but how does it go with BJT transistors from inner structure?

Comment: See e.g. http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-038.pdf "Bias  current  is  a  problem  to  the  op  amp  user  because  it  flows  in  external  impedances  and  
produces voltages, which add to system errors. Consider a non-inverting unity gain buffer driven 
from a source impedance of 1 MΩ. If IB
 is 10 nA, it will introduce an
 additional 10 mV of error. 
This degree of error is not trivial in any system. "

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, op-amp is considered to have infinite input impedance. It is assumed to have zero source/sink current from/to it's input terminals.

However, practical op-amp do have some small input current, which is mentioned in the datasheets as `input bias current`. There is also some difference between input currents of `inverting` and `non-inverting` terminals of op-amp.

You can ignore it for small-signal operation.